# In Python, is there a way to divide an element in a list by the next element in a list using a for loop or list comprehension?

Tags: pandas, list

I have a list of metrics that each have values for multiple time periods. I would like to write a script that takes a value of a metric for a particular time period and divides it by the previous year.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
for metric in metric:
    iya_df[metric+' '+period[0][-4:]+' IYA'] = pivot[metric][period[0]]/pivot[metric][period[1]]*100
    iya_df[metric+' '+period[1][-4:]+' IYA'] = pivot[metric][period[1]]/pivot[metric][period[2]]*100
    iya_df[metric+' '+period[2][-4:]+' IYA'] = pivot[metric][period[2]]/pivot[metric][period[3]]*100
    iya_df[metric+' '+period[3][-4:]+' IYA'] = pivot[metric][period[3]]/pivot[metric][period[4]]*100
```

I have a list of metrics and a list of periods. (The slicer after period is just to grab the 4 -digit year).

The source table is a pivot table with multiple indices.

I would like to change the code so that I don't have to change it if my list of time periods changes in length.

There's probably a more efficient way to do this with list comprehension than loops but I'm still getting stronger in Python.

Comment: What is `period`? Is it a dataframe, or a series? And how do you determine to use items 0, 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What about start thinking with the following two lines: `x = [1,2,3,4]` `ratio=[a/b for a,b in zip(x[1:], x)]`